# How to include json files to azure

Tags: c#, azure, entity-framework

We have 2 json files with json arrays in them, called Makes.Json and Models.Json

we then call this on local as follows for EF migration:

```
builder.HasData(SeedDataHelper.SeedFromJson<Make>("../project/Seeds/Makes.json"));
```

The seedfromjson just returns an array of the casted type.

The error when deployed to azure and running the app:

```
Could not find a part of the path 'C:\home\site\project\Seeds\Makes.json'.
```

Of course this means the file path does not exist, and kudu confirms this.
How do we go about fixing this?

The app is hosted on an App Service WebApp

Comment: This question is unanswerable without knowing what type of Azure services you are using, there's big difference between Azure VM's and Azure App Services for example.

Comment: @nbokmans sorry about that. Updated. Running a webapp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the JSON-file is part of your Visual Studio project, you can configure the property 'Copy to Output Directory':
[Visual Studio: Copying files to Debug or Release folder](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/53248.visual-studio-copying-files-to-debug-or-release-folder.aspx)

Then you are able to reference the file with the path which matches your project structure:

```
builder.HasData(SeedDataHelper.SeedFromJson<Make>("Seeds/Makes.json"));
```

Comment: It worked!, thanks!